# objective c multiple inheritance conflict with many

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I just started to build in objective c from iphone.

I have interface:

```
@interface test : UIView
```

that implements all methods from UIView, now i want it interface inherit from CDVPlugin also.
How can i do it?

i read that objective c doesn't offer multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't inherent from CDVPlugin and UIView.

I would suggest doing something like this

```
@interface test : NSObject {
    UIView *view;
    CDVPlugin *plugin;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) UIView *view;
@property(nonatomic, retain) CDVPlugin *plugin;

@end
```

and you can add methods to that class to handle anything that you're trying to do. Then just use test.view to access the view and test.plugin to access the plugin.